# How to avoid handling messages from "child" classes in Symfony Messenger?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5, symfony-messenger

I guess I'm missing something in the documentation, but the question is pretty simple.

Let's say I have a message of class `MessageOne` and `MessageTwo` which extends `MessageOne`.

I also have `MessageOneHandler` which should handle `MessageOne`:

```
__invoke(MessageOne $messageOne)
```

And `MessageTwoHandler` which should handle only `MessageTwo`:

```
__invoke(MessageTwo $messageTwo)
```

And the problem is when `MessageTwo` is dispatched it is being handled by both `MessageHandlerOne` and `MessageHandlerTwo`. Yes, it is completely sensible due to inheritance and everything is logically correct, but are there any "symfony" ways to prevent that?

Of course, I can solve this issue by reworking of the inheritance of these classes, but is there maybe a better way?

Moreover `debug:messenger` shows everything as expected, one handler per one message class without inheritance issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inheritance rarely will be a god fit for messages.

If `MessageTwo extends MessageOne`, then `$messageTwo instanceof MessageOne` would return true, simple as that.

Also, messages should be very simple and lightweight, so code repetition shouldn't be generally a concern. But if for some reason you do need to reuse some code between message classes, you have a few options:

- You could short-circuit the handling so that if `get_class($message) !== MessageOne::class` then then handler could return without doing any work... but personally I feel it would be a brittle design.

The better options are simply reworking the inheritance model for your messages.

- Shared logic between `MessageOne` and `MessageTwo` could be moved to a parent `AbstractMessage`, from which both inherit. Handlers would correctly type-hint the concrete message type, and there would be no confusion.
- Depending on the type of code reuse you are going for, you could move the shared code to a `Trait` or a helper class with static methods. If either of these are any good would depend entirely on the specifics of your application, and in the end would be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Yep, I'm already on option 1.

So it looks like I'm not missing anything and everything is just as expected?